Azure Devops - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':Myapp:lint'
I would like to run Azure pipeline for Android project and ending up with error while building.

I also have tried to include in build.grade but no luck.
android {
    ....
    ....
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

Please help to fix this.

The library is only on jcenter https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.chauthai.swipereveallayout/swipe-reveal-layout/1.4.1
so maybe you need to add it in your gradle file with
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

it will be marked as deprecated I think as jcenter is not supported anymore.

I tried this but did not help :-(

@RakeshL does it build locally?

yeah it is working in local
